# C# display the contents of an Arraylist

Tags: c#

I recently got into programming objects and I have run across a problem. I tried looking around here and I also tried to do it on my own for an hour now but it just won't display things properly. I want the program to display the first value followed by the second value so it should look something like this:

123 456 789

323 483 632

What my program is doing right now is this:

123 456 789

123 456 789

I checked the values inside my Array List and they are all unique so there are no duplicates.

Here is the Display Class

```
for (int element = 0; element < sample.Count; element++)
{
    Sample samples = (Sample)sample[element];
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", samples.CarID, samples.Cost, samples.Ins);
}
```

Comment: As an aside, use generics.  There's no need to use `ArrayList` anymore unless you have to for backwards compatibility.  On topic, we need to see how you populate that collection.

Comment: For example... https://ideone.com/yDAU7M

Comment: Maybe the CarId is the same as the cost?

Comment: Your loop code seems to be correct. So perhaps the problem is not here but in the place where you fill your ArrayList. Could you show that code?

Comment: Please show your complete code. There is not enough information to answer your question in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good idea might be to use a list of structs. First you want to define the struct...

```
struct MyStruct
    {
        public int CarID;
        public decimal Cost;
        public string Ins;
    }
```

Then you want to declare your list...

```
List<MyStruct> samples = new List<MyStruct>();
```

Then, to add to the list...

```
var MyStruct = new MyStruct();
MyStruct.CarID = carID;
MyStruct.Cost = cost;
MyStruct.Ins = "Ins";
samples.Add(MyStruct);
```

And to reference parts of the data in the list use...

```
samples[i].CarID
samples[i].Cost
samples[i].Ins
```

Really hope this helps. I have used this to do what your trying to do recently so if you need anymore information just let me know.